# java instance member corruption

Tags: java, corrupt-data

I have a Java 1.6 multi-threaded application (5-7 threads, most idle), which has a strange behavior.
The flow involves updating a device, with a 4-byte ID.
I hold the ID in a private byte-array. When the update succeeds, after ~4 seconds, the device sends a STATUS message, in which I compare it's ID with the one I'm holding, and clear the private bite-array and disable an error-timer.
All the work is done in a singleton class instance.

**The strange behavior:**
I print the value of the private byte-array from a method, which is called periodically.
Within the 4 seconds waiting for the STATUS message, the log displays a different ID (not garbage, but a 4-byte ID of a different object). Checking the value with a breakpoint shows this invalid value (meaning it's not a log error).
But, yet, when the STATUS message arrives, I compare the ID with the one I'l holding, and they match!

I moved the private member into a synchronized getter/setter, adding a log of the change, which doesn't catch the issue.

Here's a pseudo-code of my setter/getter and periodic status + the disturbing log:

```
public class Manager {
    private volatile byte[] readerID = null;

    public synchronized void setReaderID(byte[] readerID) {
        this.readerID = readerID;
        logger.debug("readerID = {}", StringUtilities.binaryToAscii(this.readerID));
    }

    public synchronized byte[] getReaderID() {
        if (this.readerID == null)
            return null;
        return Arrays.copyOf(this.readerID, this.readerID.length);
    }

    /* Called every second */
    public void periodicStatus() {
        logger.debug("readerID = {}", StringUtilities.binaryToAscii(getReaderID()));
    }
}

13:53:46,103|ad-5|INFO |Manager|readerUpdateFinish(): Received firmware install finish for reader 000189D0 at slot 0
13:53:46,103|ad-5|DEBUG|Manager|setReaderID(): readerID = 000189D0
13:53:46,103|ad-5|DEBUG|Manager|readerUpdateFinish(): triggered reader firmware timer, 1526986426103, 000189D0
13:53:46,408|ad-5|DEBUG|Manager|periodicStatus(): readerID = E69EAD03 // <- where's the setter???
13:53:50,030|ad-5|INFO |Manager|readerStatus(): Received status information for reader 000189D0 at slot 0
13:53:50,031|ad-5|DEBUG|Manager|setReaderID(): readerID = null
13:53:50,031|ad-5|DEBUG|Manager|readerStatus(): timer cleared, null
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're going to have to show some relevant code.

Comment: You have to add the remaining source code which uses this source code in a way it can be tested by everyone. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Depending on the source code we don't see, it might be possible that you change the array after you have assigned the reference to the private field.

Comment: Adding more source-code is problematic; it's quite a lot of code, running from multiple threads, according to configuration. I tried giving the minimal, a synchronized setter that logs the change and a getter that returns a copy, but yet the data seems changed within the log. More of a philosophical Java issue (from the eyes of a C-language programmer)

Comment: @RamiRosenbaum The array you are assigned to the field is known at two places. One place is the field `Manager.readerId`, the other place is where you called the `setReaderID()` method. Keep in mind that arrays are objects in java, so the reference in the `Manager.readerId` field is the same as the reference where you call the `setReaderID()` method. So when you change the array "at one place" you change the array "at the other place", because it's actually the exact same array. That's why we ask for the full MCVE, because then we can tell you where the error is.

Comment: Progman - thanks! Indeed, the readerID buffer arrives from the communication transport layer, and is an instance-member. readerID is never copied. I'll try this and update.

Comment: Progman - even with snippets of code you spotted the problem. I'm not a native Java-programmer and was thrown to this big chunk of old code. You deserve the credit.

Answer (score 0):

As Progman pointed out, readerID is passed by reference. It arrives from the transport-layer, held there as an instance-member, and is updated by the following incoming message, with the new ID, which is being displayed.